# How to get password parameter change history from profiles in oracle database

Tags: oracle, parameters, passwords, profile

I am new to oracle database. I work on oracle database 12c version. I have an audit requirement to get the details of changes made for last 1 year on password parameters in dba_profiles. Is there any audit views which can help in getting the report. Any help would be much appreciated !

Here i have resource names related to password with limit. I change the parameter PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME value to unlimited. How to find out the history of date and user details of this parameter modification.

**Output:**

```
--Profiles 
    
select profile,RESOURCE_NAME,LIMIT from dba_profiles where RESOURCE_                                      NAME like '%PASSWORD%';
    
    PROFILE                        RESOURCE_NAME                    LIMIT
    ------------------------------ -------------------------------- ----------------                                      ------------------------
    DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME               180
    MONITORING_PROFILE             PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME               DEFAULT
    DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME              UNLIMITED
    MONITORING_PROFILE             PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME              DEFAULT
    DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX               UNLIMITED
    MONITORING_PROFILE             PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX               DEFAULT
    DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION         NULL
    MONITORING_PROFILE             PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION         DEFAULT
    DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME               1
    MONITORING_PROFILE             PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME               DEFAULT
    DEFAULT                        PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME              7
    MONITORING_PROFILE             PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME              DEFAULT
    
    12 rows selected.

--Modified the value for PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME parameter 
    alter profile DEFAULT limit PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME unlimited;
    
    Profile altered.
--Date of modification    
    select sysdate from dual;
    
    SYSDATE
    ---------
    10-JUN-21
```

Comment: Did you enable auditing a year ago?  You could enable auditing going forward but you can't generate a report of the changes over the last year from before you enabled auditing.

Comment: yes audit is already enabled at db level. I need to figure out static views or columns to get the user details with date

Comment: How exactly did you enable auditing?  Are there entries in `dba_audit_trail`?

Comment: Yes there are millions of row entries in dba_audit_trail.

Comment: Are there entries for the change you just made to the profile?

Comment: Could you advice on which columns to check on dba_audit_trail?